Modal dropdowns doesn't show options from database
I used to do this at a separate window until I knew what modals are so I started converting my floating windows to modals.
This is the result after I made it into a modal
Here's the table for users database, I used sqlite3 for it.
CREATE TABLE "users" (
    "user_id"   INTEGER,
    "userstat_id"   INTEGER,
    "role_id"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "username"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "first_name"    TEXT,
    "last_name" TEXT,
    "middle_name"   TEXT,
    "email" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "password_hash" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "date_created"  DATE,
    "is_locked" BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0,
    "failed_attempts"   INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    FOREIGN KEY("role_id") REFERENCES "Roles"("role_id"),
    FOREIGN KEY("userstat_id") REFERENCES "userStatus"("userstat_id"),
    PRIMARY KEY("user_id"),
    UNIQUE("username"),
    UNIQUE("email")
);

HTML for the Page:
Below is the page's complete HTML and JavaScript code, including the modal implementation. The modal is used for adding a new user.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Users</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">
</head>
<body class="dashboard">
    <div class="sidebar-tab" id="sidebarTab">☰</div>
    <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('dashboard') }}">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('users') }}">Users</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('patients') }}">Patients</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Records</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Maintenance</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Inventory</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('reports') }}">Reports</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="logout">
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <header>
        <div class="header-left">
            <h1>Users</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="header-center">
            <form class="search-form" action="{{ url_for('search') }}" method="get">
                <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="Search...">
                <button type="submit" class="search-btn"></button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="add-user-btn" onclick="openModal()">Add User</button>
            <h2>Total Users: {{ total_users }}</h2>
            <table class="user-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Basic Info</th>
                        <th>Role</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for user in users %}
                    <tr>
                        <td class="user-info">
                            <a href="#" class="name">{{ user.name }}</a>
                            <span class="email">{{ user.email }}</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>{{ user.role }}</td>
                        <td class="status {{ user.status|lower }}">{{ user.status }}</td>
                        <td class="dropdown">
                            <button class="ellipsis-btn">⋮</button>
                            <div class="dropdown-content">
                                <a href="#" onclick="editUser({{ user.user_id }})">Edit User</a>
                                <a href="#" onclick="deleteUser({{ user.user_id }})">Delete User</a>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="pagination">
                <div class="entries">
                    Showing {{ users|length }} out of {{ total_users }} entries
                </div>
                <ul class="page-numbers">
                    <li><a href="#">&laquo; Previous</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Next &raquo;</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="userModal" class="user-modal">
        <div class="user-modal-content">
            <span class="user-modal-close" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
            <h2 class="register-user-title">Register User</h2>
            <form action="{{ url_for('submit_register_user') }}" method="POST">
                <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" required>
                <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" required>
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
                <label for="role_id">Role:</label>
                <select id="role_id" name="role_id" required>
                    {% for role in roles %}
                        <option value="{{ role.role_id }}">{{ role.role_name }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
                <label for="userstat_id">Status:</label>
                <select id="userstat_id" name="userstat_id" required>
                    {% for status in statuses %}
                        <option value="{{ status.userstat_id }}">{{ status.userStatus }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
                <button type="submit">Register</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            const sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
            const sidebarTab = document.getElementById('sidebarTab');
            const mainContent = document.querySelector('.main-content');

            sidebarTab.addEventListener('click', function () {
                sidebar.classList.toggle('show');
                mainContent.classList.toggle('shifted');
                sidebarTab.style.display = 'none';
            });

            document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                if (!sidebar.contains(event.target) && !sidebarTab.contains(event.target)) {
                    sidebar.classList.remove('show');
                    mainContent.classList.remove('shifted');
                    sidebarTab.style.display = 'block';
                }
            });

            // Dropdown functionality
            const dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');
            dropdowns.forEach(dropdown => {
                const btn = dropdown.querySelector('.ellipsis-btn');
                const content = dropdown.querySelector('.dropdown-content');

                btn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    content.classList.toggle('show');
                });

                document.addEventListener('click', function () {
                    content.classList.remove('show');
                });
            });
        });

        function openModal() {
            document.getElementById('userModal').style.display = 'block';
        }

        function closeModal() {
            document.getElementById('userModal').style.display = 'none';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

CSS for the modal:
/* User modal dropdown styles */
.user-modal select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    appearance: none;
    background: white;
    color: #000; 
}

.user-modal select:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-color: #007bff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.5);
}


That's not HTML.  That's a flask template.  You can't just load that in a browser.  You have to have a Python script as a web server running flask that fills in the template.  Do you have the Python code?

here's the python code for it
https://pastebin.com/guQF6h8W

Your code seems fine. It renders the modal correctly, however it doesn't seem that roles contains any elements. Check that you're passing down roles from your flask application.
Edit
I just noticed you provided the python code and indeed you don't pass down roles. So unless you do that with a request preprocessor, that's likely the issue.

it worked, thank you so much!
